# Developer Account Renewal - what happens if you don't renew?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I'm a registered Apple Developer and I don't want to renew right now because I'm not currently working on iOS apps and may not be for the next year. I understand my apps will be taken out of sale, and that's cool with me.

My question is (since Apple don't clarify this themselves): 
Are the apps also removed from iTunes Connect? i.e. If I decide to reopen my account in the future, will they be available for sale just by flipping a switch, or would I need to re-build and re-upload them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your contract is over, the apps are removed from the App Store.

When you decide to renew the account, the apps are ready to be in the App Store, though probably you'll need to re-accept the contracts. So, after you accepted the contracts again, your apps are in the App Store again.